# Using F-test vs. AICc in Mixed Model Selection

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I am creating a mixed model in R using the lme4() package. I fit my full model using the lmer() function, with a single random effect.

```
lme0 = lmer(L50 ~ (1|SITE2) + compost + ZONE + POSITION + 
PRED_BIOMASS + CS_DENSITY + RICHNESS + CHLA_RASTER + SST_RASTER, data = gbr)
```

I am confused on how to proceed with model selection. A stepwise approach, a la dredge(), suggests the following as the 'best' model, one with almost all predictors retained:

```
head(dredge(lme0))
Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
Global model call: lmer(formula = L50 ~ (1 | SITE2) + compost + ZONE + POSITION + 
    PRED_BIOMASS + CS_DENSITY + RICHNESS + CHLA_RASTER + SST_RASTER, 
    data = gbr)
---
Model selection table 
      (Int) CHL_RAS POS     RIC SST_RAS ZON df   logLik  AICc delta weight
202 -147.40   21.98   +           13.65   +  8 -160.115 340.0  0.00  0.559
```

But when I apply the lmerTest:step() function, which uses an F test as opposed to an AICc value, the 'best' fit model has **only one fixed and one random parameter**. I know that the step() function uses maximum liklehihod to fit the random effects, and doesn't seem to compare models on AIC.

```
s <- lmerTest::step(lme0)

s
Random effects:
      Chi.sq Chi.DF elim.num p.value
SITE2  12.96      1     kept   3e-04

Fixed effects:
                Sum Sq   Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value elim.num Pr(>F)
PRED_BIOMASS    0.0090    0.0090     1 20.59  0.0002        1 0.9898
compost         1.3192    1.3192     1 26.23  0.0259        2 0.8735
CS_DENSITY      7.9498    7.9498     1 35.78  0.1634        3 0.6885
SST_RASTER     27.2554   27.2554     1 25.66  0.5660        4 0.4587
ZONE           89.9116   44.9558     2 19.06  0.9115        5 0.4187
RICHNESS       62.6404   62.6404     1 37.94  1.2645        6 0.2679
CHLA_RASTER   153.7626  153.7626     1 42.82  3.0935        7 0.0858
POSITION     3518.9881 3518.9881     1 22.90 63.8783     kept <1e-07

Least squares means:
                POSITION Estimate Standard Error   DF t-value Lower CI Upper CI p-value    
POSITION  Mid        1.0   236.56           5.35 23.5   44.24      226      248  <2e-16 ***
POSITION  Outer      2.0   187.55           3.00 21.0   62.43      181      194  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Differences of LSMEANS:
                     Estimate Standard Error   DF t-value Lower CI Upper CI p-value    
POSITION Mid - Outer     49.0           6.13 22.9    7.99     36.3     61.7  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Final model:
lme4::lmer(formula = L50 ~ (1 | SITE2) + POSITION, data = gbr, 
    contrasts = list(POSITION = "contr.SAS"))
```

Please help me understand what the fundamental difference is between the dredge() and step() functions. **Why would these two approaches result in two very different 'best' models?**

I'll add that the AICc for step()'s best model is higher than the one proposed by dredge():

```
lme1 = lmer(L50 ~ (1|SITE2) + POSITION, data = gbr)
AICc(lme1)
[1] 359.5486
```

Let me know if you need more information,
Thanks!

Comment: Using F-test automatic backward elimination as the one you suggest regarding  `lmerTest:step()` is a pretty bad idea to use when it comes to model selection. Conceptually `AICc` is a bit better but only just a bit. Please see this thread on [algorithms for automatic model selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836). In short, I do not believe the inference produced by F-test backwards elimination because it is very likely to overfit.